# How to improve speed execution when using LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Case: I need a sp that checks whether only one parameter is not null and execute the select statement that searchs the LIKE operator in only one column for speed reasons

I wanna do the following in the most efficient way for speed execution reason

```
IF(@MiddleName ='' AND @LastName='')
BEGIN SELECT Name, MiddleName, LastName, Age, Address, Location, Company 
FROM People WHERE (Name LIKE '%'+@Name+'%')
END
BEGIN
IF(@LastName ='' AND @Name='')
BEGIN SELECT Name, MiddleName, LastName, Age, Address, Location, Company
FROM People WHERE (MiddleName LIKE '%'+@MiddleName+'%')
```

And so on for each column, as you can see I would need to do all possible combinations
You may ask why not use `NOT ''` in the target column? that's because there's one last select that checks all columns in case all parameters aren't null

Edit: query already works I'm asking how to improve it

Comment: You should look into full text indexes.

Comment: Do not work. Query is non seargeable.

Comment: `''` and `NULL` are not the same. You say you are checking if the variable is not `NULL` but you aren't; you're checking if the string has a 0 length.

Comment: Question updated for those who commented

Answer (score 3):

First, you are better off with dynamic SQL.

Second, LIKE "%@MIddleName%" is NOT how parameters work - LIKE @Parameter works, but you cCAN NOT put the @parameter IN A string. Simply will not be parsed. Period. You basically need to work with Dynamic SQL and use sp_executesql.

And your queries with %value% are per definition NOT sargeable, so normal indices do not work. There is not a lot you CAN do - it will do a table scan. There are some workarounds (building your own indices with triggers) but I doubt you could do that - it is EXTREMELY complex. The additional index table will have to contain every possible word combination, cutting down initial letters (I.e. none, first, second etc.) to allow to be sargeable. You successfully hit a weak point in SQL Server. Make sure the query or connection parameters do not leave more locks than needed. All you can do.

Comment: `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` has been shown to work very well as well; provided the OP is on 2008+: https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: Not really. Option recompile has reasons, but the OP tries to avoid having the SQL - not the same.

Comment: My comment in is reference to the dynamic SQL specifically; probably should have mentioned that. If you don't believe so though, Gail's article is a good read.